# Lax pair and cubic nonlinear Schrödinger equation

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, mp.mathematical-physics

Motivation: I'm trying to understand the Section 4 in the this [section 4 in paper" Low regularity conservation laws for integrable PDE by Killip-Visan-Zhang](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.05362.pdf) ö

It reads as follows: many completely integrable PDE admit a Lax pair of the following form:
$$\frac{d}{dt} L(t,\kappa)=[P(t, \kappa), L(t, \kappa)]$$
with $$L(t,\kappa)= \begin{bmatrix} -\partial+ \kappa & iq(x)\\
\mp I \bar{q}(x) & -\partial-\kappa \end{bmatrix} $$

and some operator pencil $P(t, \kappa).$

My Question: Can we say following cubic NLS
$$-i\frac{d}{dt}q= -\beta(t)q'' \pm 2|q|^2q$$
where  $\beta(t+1)=\beta(t)$ for all $t\in \mathbb R$ and $\beta$ is piecewise constant with finitely many discontinuity in $[0,1],$ admit aLax pair?  If so what is $L$ and $P$?

Answer (score 2):

The existence of Bäcklund transformations and associated linear problems for generalised nonlinear Schrödinger equations of the form $z_{xx} +iz =f(z,z^*)$ has been analysed by

Harnad and Winternitz, *Pseudopotentials and Lie symmetries for the generalised nonlinear Schrödinger equation*, J. Math. Phys. **23**(4), April 1982

It should be possible - at least formally - to extend their analysis to your case.

Because your PDE includes an independent variable in the coefficients, you may also wish to review the note by B.A. Kupershmidt, *Nonautonomous form of the theory of Lax equations*, Lettere al Nuovo Cimento **33** (1982) 103–107.